# Remove items from array -by value not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I'm stuck on a simple thing of removing an item(object) from an array in JavaScript. I am also using jQuery.

I'm trying to build RSS feed and for that I'm storing bookmark/favorites functionality in `localStorage`. I need to add/remove items from `loalStorage array` as and when user clicks of the `glyphicon-star` and `glyphicon-star-empty` respectively.

The problem I'm facing is during unfavoriting an item. i.e: removing object from array. THe user may click on any favorited item(random order) to unfavorite it. For that I need to remove the respective item from `localstorage` by value as the index may not always be known. I did search for a valid solution using `grep` and implemented in my code, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

This is what I found and implemented but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-star', function(){
   var y = arr;
   var removeItem = obj;
   arr = $.grep(arr, function(value) {
       return value != obj;
  });
 localStorage.favorite = JSON.stringify(arr);
 console.log(arr);
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
   console.log(arr[i]);
}
});
```

Here is the working: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLzvc9zf/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix for your fiddle

```
  arr = $.grep(arr, function(value) {
        return JSON.stringify(value) != JSON.stringify(obj);
            localStorage.favorite = JSON.stringify(arr);
            console.log(arr);
        });
```

demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tLzvc9zf/6/)

Comment: it works fine for it but when i add further implementation i.e viewing bookmarks (click on `.glyphicon-bookmark` near 'RSS') it doesn't remove elements from there when `.glyphicon-star` is clicked.. here's is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1nbxfg8d/1/

Comment: hi, a gentle request, if you can please help :(

Comment: the issue is in createObj function

Comment: function createObj(selectedClass) {
  var $this = selectedClass;
  obj = {
      title: $($this).closest('.data-title').find(".panel-heading").text(),
      con: $($this).closest('.data-title').next('.data-content').html()
    }
    //console.log(obj.title);
}

Answer (score 0):

Object comparison is a little bit tricky to achieve, check this post for info and samples: [LINK](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html)

You can just add that function to your code and edit your `$.grep` as follows:

```
arr = $.grep(arr, function(value) {
    return isEquivalent(value, obj) === false;
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tLzvc9zf/8/)